# Need to join two tables and display data under some conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables table A and table B

table A :-

```
NAME     SUR        SUB
Rakesh   sharma    Maths
Arti     Agrwal    English
Arti     Sharma     English
yash     gupta     hindi
umir    abdul      Science
```

table B:-

```
NAME     SUR        SUB
Rakesh   sharma    Maths
Arti     Agrwal    English
Arti     Sharma     English
yash     gupta     hindi
umir    abdul      Science
ramesh   agrahari   science 
piyush   jain        english 
priyam    tiwari     maths
```

write the query to display this result?
As it should like " SUR should all but including SUR LIKE 'agr%' like this also, and ignore that data which is not there in table A as compare to table B.

In SUR column need to display all the records which has same combination (name,sur,sub) and is there in table A and table B while we join the tables.
If we can see there is SUR (Agrwal in table A  and Agrahari in table B) but Agrahari is not in table A but we need to display that also while apply SUR like 'Agr%' condition in the query.

And rest all data also should be displayed.

Final display:-

```
NAME     SUR        SUB
Rakesh   sharma    Maths
Arti     Agrwal    English
Arti     Sharma     English
yash     gupta     hindi
umir    abdul      Science
ramesh   agrahari   science
```

Please help me with this!!

Comment: I've removed the tag `plsql`, because this is not about Oracle's programming language PL/SQL, but about SQL. I've also removed the tag `oracle-sqldeveloper`, because SQL Developer is just one of the tools to run SQL queries, and it doesn't matter which tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this as follows: You want to select all rows from B that have an exact match in A or the SUR of which starts with 'agr' (or 'Agr', etc., i.e. not case sensitive).

Use `UPPER` and `LIKE` for a non case sensitive comparison and `IN` or `EXISTS` for the lookup in the other table.

```
select *
from b
where upper(sur) like 'AGR%'
or (name, sur, sub) in (select name, sur, sub from a);
```